# The overlay window became all greyed

Tags: drupal

After upgrading to CiviCRM 4.6.5, I cannot access any more to any popup window. This overlay window is somehow slightly greyed. 
It doesn't react anymore (not event the cancel button) and the only way to remove the window is pressing the escape button.

[image]

In drupal administration I have this warning :

Warning : array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given dans civicrm_permission() (ligne 67 dans /home/website/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module).

Is it a Drupal issue or a Civi one ?

Thanks for advice and help.

====

Comment: Please first go through the [CiviCRM js troubleshooting steps](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850) and then edit your question with more details.

Comment: @Coleman, I enabled the backtrace => nothing is shown in this popup case.

Comment: @Coleman 
with the Inspect Element of Chrome, this message is displayed : 
`Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.`

Comment: That's not an error (just a random deprecation notice) and is not relevant. Are you sure there are no errors anywhere?

Comment: @Coleman No there no error shown in the Drupal journal nor the Chrome feed back and the Civiback back-trace…

Comment: pmoz Yes // I tried several browsers. Similar problem. heather-o // Great suggestion ! Thanks. Coleman // Thanks as well. I am looking for a way to disable the drupal css. About changing theme, I tried several but all carry the jquery and css. I keep you informed.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, css from your drupal site is majorly interfering with CiviCRM. Specifically, the interference is targeting jQuery UI, probably because you have a copy of jQuery UI loading via Drupal. Try:

- Disabling the jQuery UI module (or find a way to disable it just for CiviCRM pages)
- Choosing a simpler theme for CiviCRM pages, particularly one that does not bundle a copy of jQuery UI.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of clicking the link that triggers the pop up, can you right-click and 'open in new tab' so that you have the form as a page rather than a pop up? Does that work fine? If so, when you are getting the pop-up do you have any errors if you right-click on the pop up and Inspect Element?

(Edited to included Heather O. comment) If that is the case, then you can disable the pop-ups in the Administration console under Display Preferences civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display&reset=1 Means that members of staff can access as normal in the meantime.

Comment: Yes Pete, the  right-click with 'open in new tab' works fine in a new tab. I can then edit ! But if I inspect the element pop-up I get this message : Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: Can't help - but it at least means civi is not 'unusable' so perhaps you could tweak your question.

Comment: // yes thanks. I can use Civi with right clic open in another window or tab.

Comment: Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: FYI whilst you're working out the specific issue, you can disable the pop-ups in the Administration console under Display Preferences civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display&reset=1 Means that members of staff can access as normal in the meantime.

Comment: I did follow the advice of Heather O. but I quickly encounter same problem : e.g. to record a mailing template we must use a pop-u ! So back to square one on this issue…

Answer (score 0):

We just got a bug report in our issue tracker about this:
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16935

Looks like a recent change to the Drupal Media module is to blame.